# String manipulation of jquery attr, not working for me

Tags: jquery, string, attr

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var image = $('*[data-name="slider_image"]');

        image.each(function() {
            var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

            console.log(source);

            source.slice(0, -11);

            console.log(source);
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to get the href attribute of each image, and cut of the last 11 characters. The output I'm getting is the exact same before and after I apply slice. On Jquery's homepage they write that the data that attr returns is a string, so I don't see what the problem is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add your code to fiddle

Comment: @LaxmikantDange: Better yet, Stack Snippet right there on site (Johan, it's the `<>` button in the editor toolbar).

Comment: Thank you for showing that. I updated my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the value returned by the slice method and assign to a variable to refer the updated value. the slice method does not modify the original string

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var image = $('*[data-name="slider_image"]');

  image.each(function() {
    var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

    console.log(source);

    var modified = source.slice(0, -11);

    snippet.log(source + ':' + modified);
  });

});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-name="slider_image">
  <img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=text01234567890" />
</div>
<div data-name="slider_image">
  <img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=text01234567890" />
</div>
<div data-name="slider_image">
  <img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=text01234567890" />
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed this is the right answer, you can read more there : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice "the slice() method returns a shallow copy[...]" but you have to mix it with @Curt answer

Comment: Ah, thank you. Stupid mistake! I will accept your answer as soon as I'm able to.

Comment: @SecularKid No, the end index if negative is taken from the end of the source. This answer is fine as-is

Answer (score 2):

```
source.slice(0, -11)
```

does NOT modify the original input `source`

Try:

```
var tmp = source.slice(0, -11);
console.log(tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

`source.slice(0, -11);
console.log(source);`

do:

```
    console.log(source.slice(0, -11));
```

or store it in a variable:

`var output=source.slice(0, -11);
console.log(output);`